# Excel Inserting Function Columns Utilizing a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I would like is a macro that after every 4 rows it inserts a function column which for row 3 down will include a function and rows 1 & 2 would be identical to the previous one and row 3 would say Planned orders.

I would like to add this identical macro to create every 5 after this one, then one for every 6 and one for every 7.

It can be 4 macros I just have to click in the right order not anything to fancy.

I created the macro below which inserts a row every 4th column, but I have to move the table over three columns to begin with and it doesn't generate the last column. How could I get the functions I want added to this column?

```
Sub insert_column_after_interval_4()

  Dim iLastCol As Integer

  iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' same as CTRL+RIGHT ARROW

  For colx = 5 To iLastCol Step 5

     Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

  Next

End Sub
```

Picture included for how the table currently looks, the end result would be just 4 additional formula columns after that and after every subsequent 4 columns in the spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. Just to be clear, you want four Columns to be added after every forth column? Then you want to be able to do the same for every 5th, 6th and 7th Columns?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will insert 3 `Columns` after every fourth Column, the first column will be added into the sixth Column and then from there after every four columns there will be three columns inserted.

The data from the last two columns in the set of four columns will be pasted into the fist two columns of the new columns.

Two things to remember. You always want to use direct referencing to `WorkBooks` `WorkSheets` to avoid confusion in the program when multiple `WorkBooks` and `WorkSheets` are available.

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub InsertingColumns()

      'Always want to directly reference the WorkBook and WorkSheet which contains your data
      'Change Book1 and Sheet1 as per your requirement
      Dim CurrentWorkSheet As Worksheet
      Set CurrentWorkSheet = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")

      Dim LastColumn As Long
      LastColumn = CurrentWorkSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

      'Step 7 to cater for the every forth Column plus the 7 columns being added
      'Started at 6 because "After every four columns" means the fith Column and catering for the Cal Day in Column 1
      Dim CurrentColumn As Long
      For CurrentColumn = 6 To LastColumn Step 7

           'Current Column to CurrentColumn + 2 will have 3 Cells selected
           CurrentWorkSheet.Range(Cells(1, CurrentColumn), Cells(1, CurrentColumn + 2)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

           'Copy Data from the second column from the right and paste into the first new column
           CurrentWorkSheet.Columns(CurrentColumn - 2).Copy
           CurrentWorkSheet.Columns(CurrentColumn).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

           'Copy Data from the first column from the right and paste into the second new column
           CurrentWorkSheet.Columns(CurrentColumn - 1).Copy
           CurrentWorkSheet.Columns(CurrentColumn + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


      Next CurrentColumn

 End Sub
```

See BEFORE and AFTER Below:

[image]

For the 5, 6 and 7 inserts you can then just edit this four insert loop to cater for the others.